# Laravel Blade Template With Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a template `admin.blade.php` that contains this code:

```
@yield('breadcrumbs', Breadcrumbs::render(Request::route()->getName()))
```

And in my child files I either ignore breadcrumbs or I would like to do something like:

```
@section('breadcrumbs')
    {{ Breadcrumbs::render(Request::route()->getName(), $event) }}
@endsection
```

The problem is that it seems that the default yield content is still being triggered and when the function gets called I get an error.

> Too few arguments to function
>   DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::{closure}(), 1
>   passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\msu\vendor\davejamesmiller\laravel-breadcrumbs\src\BreadcrumbsGenerator.php
>   on line 68 and exactly 2 expected (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\msu\resources\views\event\station\edit.blade.php)

Which I understand, so my question is how do I achieve what I am trying to do in blade?

I also tried doing @section @show and section @stop but that seems to just hide the sections and give me the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `{{ Breadcrumbs::render(Request::route()->getName(), $event) }}` is returning something?

Comment: I have that code in the child blade and *sometimes* it does or would return something. The issue is before that when $event is present then the default content still calls render and it throws the error. I want it more like an if statement. Where if $event = null use the default content. Otherwise, use the child section. (for example)

Comment: Can't you do something like `@if ($event != null) @section('breadcrumbs') ... @endif` inside your child view?

Comment: Well the thing is that $event is just an example. That variable could be pretty much anything. I am  not going to want to write an if statement checking for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a component to handle the if case you are going to need:

```
<!-- resources/views/breadcrumb.blade.php -->

@if (isset($slot) && !is_null($slot))
    @section ('breadcrumbs')
        {{ Breadcrumbs::render(Request::route()->getName(), $slot) }}
    @endsection
@endif
```

Then inside your child view, you can call your component:

```
<!-- resources/views/child.blade.php -->

@component('breadcrumb', ['slot' => $event]) @endcomponent
```

You can update the variable name in the component to whatever you like.

For more information about components: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: I see what you mean now. I think this will work. Thank you!